# Добавление кастомных полей

Tags: java, hibernate

В вэб-приложении есть форма, в которую нужно реализовать возможность добавлять кастомные поля с обозначением типа. Какие варианты (в общем) есть для решения данной задачи? Первое, что приходит в голову - это хранить в БД поля в виде JSON. Есть у кого еще какие идеи? JAVA-HIBERNATE-REACT. Рендер полей на форме - Мета из бэка.

Comment: JSON — самое простое, если у вас реляционная БД. Если нереляционная — подумайте в сторону дополнительных полей в документах, но при этом чтобы они не наползали на уже имеющеся поля (т.е., в форме кто-то добавил кастомное поле id и поломал БД).

Comment: БД реляционная - Oracle 12. А есть еще идеи?

Comment: [EAV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: Значит, JSON и динамическая проверка. Здесь БД вам сильно не поможет, только код (ну и, видимо, больше модульных тестов в этом мест),